# pytest : how to parametrize a test with every fixtures satisfying a certain condition

Tags: pytest, fixtures

I have a large set of scenarios defined as pytest fixtures. I would like to run my test suite with all these scenarios. The following example gives a quite satisfying solution :

```py
import pytest

# ----------------------------------------
# My scenarios
@pytest.fixture()
def scn_1():
    return 1

@pytest.fixture()
def scn_2():
    return 2

@pytest.fixture()
def scn_3():
    return 3

# -------------------------------------------------
# A fixture collecting all the scenarios
@pytest.fixture(params=['scn_1', 'scn_2', 'scn_3'])
def scn_result(request):
    scn_name = request.param
    return request.getfixturevalue(scn_name)

# ----------------------------------------------
# my test suite
def test_a(scn_result):
    assert scn_result in [1,2,3]

def test_b(scn_result):
    assert scn_result in [1,2,3,4]
```

The problem is that I have to list manually all the fixture names. Is there a way to parametrize the fixture `scn_result` with all the fixture whose name starts with "scn_" ? Or any solution allowing to parametrize automatically the tests with all these fixtures.

Comment: what is the issue with typing out all the fixtures?

Comment: @gold_cy Thanks for your comment. This can be annoying if the number of scenarios increases or if their names change. I would like to automate as much as possible.